# Issues in creating bot service on Azure

Tags: azure, botframework

today when I try to create a bot service on Azure, the platform give a Web APP, not the bot project, any ideas?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Tú, si tú, el que votó negativo, tal vez tengas alguna idea de por qué está ocurriendo esto, precisamente hoy, ¿actualización de la plataforma?, ¿bug en el servicio?

Comment: What issues are you seeing?  What error message are you getting?  What is the behavior?

Comment: Hi JasonSowers, in the last 3 month the bot service project had an structure, right now, and on my account (dont know why!, on my teammate is okay) the bot service give me another structure. It´s not an error, I was wondering what happen!?!?, I assume is an upgrade. 
My teammate can create the usual bot service project, but not me, not with my Azure' s subcription.

Answer (score 0):

Just to finish this issue, I upgraded my project's structure and it's working like usual.